# Custom Post Type pages are "not found"

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I've created two new Custom Post types using code that I've used successfully on other projects without issue. The first is called `top_charts`, the other `case_studies`, and both appear correctly in the admin menu and I can create new posts.

Unfortunately the new posts don't appear. I just get a `404.php` response.

I've created an `archive-top_charts.php` to see if I can get anything to appear, but I see a `404.php` "page not found" reply.

I originally named the custom posts `top-charts` and `case-studies`, but I thought the hyphen might have been the problem, and so renamed them to use an underscore instead. It hasn't helped.

I've tried re-saving my Permalinks, but nothing has changed. My .htaccess page looks like what you'd expect, too (and other pages works fine). What else can I check?

Comment: have you used flush_rewrite_rules( false ); in register post type? for more details follow this link http://nooshu.com/page-not-found-with-custom-post-types

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the link to the post itself, but not the `archive-top_charts.php` page. Strange!

Comment: Just adding part of it in answer that may help other users and try to look for archive as well.

Comment: found the simple answer to this bug on another stack post:
[Custom Post Type Permalink Page Not Found](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169311/custom-post-type-permalink-page-not-found)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For fixing custom post not found please use below code in your `functions.php`:

```
flush_rewrite_rules( false );
```

You should only do this as a temporary measure otherwise it will run on every page load.

For more details please follow [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140403185155/https://nooshu.com/page-not-found-with-custom-post-types)

As for the `archive-top_charts.php` not appearing, make sure you have `'has_archive'   => true` when you're registering your post type.

Comment: great you found 'has_archive' :)

Comment: why does this still work? and why isn't this a wordpress bug?

Answer (score 43):

You don't have to edit your php code!

While you can do this in the function that registers your custom post type, like the other answers, you can also do this in the settings menu, thus avoiding touching your php code:

To flush WordPress rewrite rules or permalinks (usually needs to be done manually for new custom post types) from the Dashboard:

1. In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks".
2. Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes".
3. Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.

It's that simple!

[image: image of saving permalinks page]
[reference](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I believe I also needed `has_archive`, but good to know you can force a flush through the menu.

Comment: Is there any way to save changes to (update) permalinks automatically rather than going to Settings > Permalinks every time a CPT category/term is added? Like how will non-admin be able to do this if they don't have access to settings? Can a hook be called when adding a new category to flush permalinks automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is late in the game (and may not be the related problem), but I wanted to point out to others a possible issue.

In my case, I had set my taxonomy rewrite to tools and the content type rewrite to the same thing. Therefore, it would never work properly as it was a conflict. Unfortunately, there is no detection for such a thing so I figured I would just point it out to others.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this line for rewrite rules this was the reason for me.
after comment or removed it solved but you can make it true also.

```
flush_rewrite_rules( true );
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was missing rights in my development folder so .htaccess file could not have been created ad/or modified.

So manual flushing or Saving changes in WP Permalinks was not helping.

Solution was to create .htaccess file by myself

Comment: I follow the way of @David Salcer, created a htaccess file and then it works.