# New custom PHP pages are getting 404s

Tags: permalinks

When I create new php pages and try to visit them I am receiving a 404. For example, I have created the file `page-tacos.php` (stored in my child theme directory) but when I try to visit the URL at `localhost:8888/tacos` I am getting a 404.

I have added several custom pages in the past and whenever I was having this issue I would follow the advice from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202859/custom-post-type-pages-are-not-found) and it would fix my problem. However, now flushing my rewrite rules is not fixing it.

I have tried renaming my file to not include the 'page-' prefix, resaving my permalinks, and running `flush_rewrite_rules( false );` to no avail.

My .htaccess file has not changed.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: I believe the mental model of how things work is back to front here. The page loads the template, not the other way around

Comment: On further reflection, the tacos template appears to be a complete non-issue, and the actual problem being described is that permalinks aren't working at all. Can you confirm that permalinks work at all? E.g. can you access posts? Date archives? Author archives? Other post types? Or are all permalinks broken? Have they ever worked in the past on this site? What kind of server is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), creating the file `page-tacos.php` in your active theme will create the template that would be used to view the page with slug `tacos`, but it *doesn't create the page*. You also need to [add the page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Pages) in WordPress's backend.

Comment: I did add the page page-tacos.php to my backend within my child themes directory like all of my other custom pages.

Comment: Yes, but just creating a page template file *does not add the page* to WordPress. You still need to create the page in WordPress's admin area.

Answer (score 2):

Things have been done backwards here, in a rather literal way. Templates don't determine the content/URL. Content/URL determines the template.

If you create a page `test` at `/test` it will load `page.php`, but you can add `page-test.php` and it will choose the most specific template it has available, allowing you to override just that page.

Here is what happens when you load a URL:

- WP processes the URL
- The URL gets turned into query parameters ( the same ones that go into `WP_Query` or `get_posts` ), this is where permalinks/rewrite rules are done
- It looks at these parameters and figures out if it's an archive or a search page etc
- It then runs the query and fetches the posts
- THEN it figures out which template to load, based on the parameters.

It's a common misconception that WP takes a URL and loads a template, and which template is loaded determines the content, but that's not true.

WP uses the template hierarchy to figure out which template to load, so you can use that to make its template selection more specific/bespoke.

Comment: @jrquick you couldn't possibly have created other pages that way in the past, not without going into the pages admin and creating a new page of that name, something you clearly stated wasn't done in your original question. Re-read the answer and you'll see that you need to create the `test` page, you can't just create a template and assume that's all you need to do

Comment: Or is your problem with pages a complete red herring? Is it really that you can't get permalinks to work at all? And this tacos page is just an example? Do any permalinks of any kind work? Date archives? Posts?